# how to change number row color in visual studio ETL

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I know this question might be selected as a duplicate question but I couldn't figure it out how to change number row colour in SSIS visual studio ETL? I choose dark them but the background of the page is still white. and I cannot read the number of items extract. please help me.

I am using VS2017 community edition, windows server 2016 standard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is connected to a bug in a visual studio related to color themes. Can you try switching it to light and then to black till this issue is gone.

Alternative variant is to download [Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor)
and adjust it manualy

Comment: I did but nothing changed. I do agree with you it could be due to a bug

Comment: Perhaps then a Color Theme Editor for VS?

Comment: Thanks man your solution is working, however, the dark theme having the same issue but I managed to use other themes which were working fine on my pc. I am using VM and VM is using standard VGA graphic card, do you think is there any relation between this problem and type of VGA?